# event handler in Ext.grid.Panel

Tags: extjs, gridview, event-handling

Using ExtJS 5.1.0 and I stumbled across this blog post: http://www.learnsomethings.com/2014/11/13/extjs-5-action-column-item-viewcontroller-handler-binding/ ... it saved a TON of configuration work when referencing controller methods, since I can reference methods in my controller without the need for any explicit config objects in the controller. I have utilized it in many forms in my app with no problem.

All that is needed is to add the method name to the handler reference like so:

```
handler: 'methodReference'
```

and voilà!

However, now I am trying to get it to work with the following Ext.grid.Panel, with no success:

```
Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.view.grid.Criteria', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    xtype: 'framing-buttons',
    store: 'Payload',

    controller: 'main-view',
    requires: [
        'cardioCatalogQT.view.main.MainController'
    ],

    columns: [
        {text: "Description", flex: 1, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'description'},
        {text: "Type", width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'type'},
        {text: "Operator", width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'comparatorSymbol'},
        {text: "Value", width: 120, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'value'}
    ],
    columnLines: true,
    selModel: {
        type: 'checkboxmodel',
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: 'onSelectionChange'
        }
    },

    // This view acts as the default listener scope for listeners declared within it.
    // For example the selectionModel's selectionchange listener resolves to this.
    defaultListenerScope: true,

    // This view acts as a reference holder for all components below it which have a reference config
    // For example the onSelectionChange listener accesses a button using its reference
    referenceHolder: true,

    onSelectionChange: function(sm, selections) {
        this.getReferences().removeButton.setDisabled(selections.length === 0);
    },

    // inline buttons
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        ui: 'footer',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [{
            minWidth: 80,
            text: 'Execute',
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'executeTest',
            handler: 'onExecuteClick'
        }]
        }, {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            reference: 'removeButton',  // The referenceHolder can access this button by this name
            text: 'Remove Criterion',
            tooltip: 'Remove the selected item',
            iconCls: 'remove',
            disabled: false
        }]
    }],

    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    alias: 'widget.criteriaGrid',
    title: 'Search',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.width = 750;
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

The handler reference to onExecuteClick (`handler: 'onExecuteClick'`) in my docked itms is not registering with the controller (getting a "no method" error), although it works just fine from a different Ext.form.Panel. I have the desired controller defined in the requires attribute and even reference the controller via the controller reference.

All my forms, and the grid are referenced in the Main view via aliased xtypes, as in

```
{
    xtype: 'criteriaGrid'
}
```

and render just fine. The ONLY thing that does not work is that the event handler is not registering via the grid panel. I can always create a fiddle for this if needed, but I think my issue and the desired behavior is pretty clear.

Comment: Tried changing  defaultListenerScope to false?

Comment: Sweet! That did it. Ha! (I had initially just commented it out altogether, but the default for this attribute must be true).

I would accept your answer, but it was not in the form of an answer, just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set defaultListenerScope to false.

```
defaultListenerScope : false
```

This is what the API doc has to say about - [defaultListenerScope](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-defaultListenerScope)

> If true, this component will be the default scope (this pointer) for
>   events specified with string names so that the scope can be
>   dynamically resolved. The component will automatically become the
>   defaultListenerScope if a controller is specified.